# Word frequency counter, list not working correctly

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, frequency

I have some code that computes word frequencies in a given ArrayList of words. I have a frequency class which essentially stores the word and its respective frequency. Here is my code:

```
public static List<Frequency> computeWordFrequencies(List<String> words) {
        List<String> wordsList = words; 
        String[] wordsArray = wordsList.toArray(new String[0]);
        Arrays.sort(wordsArray);
        Set<String> noDuplicates = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(wordsArray));
        List<Frequency> frequencies = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String word : noDuplicates) {
            int wordFrequency = Collections.frequency(words, word);
            Frequency newFrequency = new Frequency(word, wordFrequency);
            System.out.println(newFrequency.toString());
            frequencies.add(newFrequency);
        }
        for (Frequency f : frequencies) {
            System.out.println(f.getText()+"               "+f.getFrequency());
        }
        return frequencies; 
    }
```

For reference, Frequency class:

```
public class Frequency {

    private final String word;
    private static int frequency;

    public Frequency(String word) {
        this.word = word;
        frequency = 0;
    }

    public Frequency(String word, int newfrequency) {
        this.word = word;
        this.frequency = newfrequency;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return word;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public static void setFrequency(int newFrequency) {
        frequency = newFrequency;
    }

    public void incrementFrequency() {
        frequency++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return word + ":" + frequency;
    }

}
```

I inserted print statements in my code and this is some of the output:

> wrapping:1 yard:3 yarn:2 year:2 yet:1 yukon:1 zero:2 abandoned
>   2 accordion               2 acequia               2 across
>   2 added               2

So when the frequencies are created, they have the right frequency, but somehow they later all get changed to 2. What's even more weird is that if I change the second print statement to f.toString(), even the first print statement shows only 2 for the frequencies like this:

> rising:2 river:2 riveredge:2 riversound:2 road:2 roadrunners:2
>   roadside:2 roast:2

Can anyone tell me why all of the frequencies get set to 2, or where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `static` from

```
private static int frequency
```

You want an individual instance variable for each word, not one class variable for all words.

---

Also, I would recommend a `Hashmap<String, Integer>` for a frequency counter instead of creating any wrapper objects because...

1. There is no reason to convert a list to an array, then to a Set, and back to a list
2. You don't need to sort a list before removing duplicates
3. `Collections.frequency` within a loop has O(n^2) runtime